# Quicker algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, depth-first-search

I have undirected, unweighed graph. I have a file that contains list of pairs (connected nodes). Each node may have any number of neighbours. I have to find one or all possible ways to traverse from a specified node to  another.

I tried the depth first search - it works pretty well but my friends suggest that it may be pretty slowly. What other algorithms would you suggest? Could you please provide example pseudo code for them?

Comment: `I have to find one or all possible ways from specified node to the other` Those are completely different problems, which is it - one or all?

Comment: A "quickest algorithm" just doesnt exist. It's all a matter of some factors.

Comment: Unfortunately program asks user to choose if he/she is interested in finding one solution or all possible solutions. If it may help the graphs provided to the program are completely random. They may have 10 nodes as well as 800 nodes. They may contain loops. There might be no solution to the graph. Maybe I should use 2 different algorithms? Which one then would you suggest?

Comment: Goodluck finding all paths in graphs with 800 nodes. Even if you are looking only for *simple paths* (otherwise there are infinite number of paths), the number of paths is still exponential in the number of nodes.

Comment: Make sure you've read your specifications correctly. It's usual when doing path finding to either find the quickest route to one specific node or to all other nodes (not all possible routes between two nodes as that is an infinite number without applying some restrictions)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem would be a way to find a solution where you could assign each edge a weight of one to look for short solutions. I would question how are you supposed to handle cycles as this could generate infinite solutions depending on how many times one goes through the cycle similar to the challenge of the Halting Problem.

Comment: @amit: In fact the number of simple paths is *superexponential* in the number of nodes, assuming the graph is dense.  In a complete graph with n nodes, there are (n-2)! such paths, which grows faster than c^n for any fixed c.